# Primefaces wizard. How to return js function tab for onnext

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, wizard

I use Primefaces 3.5. And try to call js function in onnext handler of `<p:wizard/>`.
I want that onnext return on tab on specific tab after validation result ob current tab. My validation function

```
    function validateManageOtherTournaments(wizard, validationTab, lang) {
                var currentTabId = validationTab;
                if (currentTabId != 'competitionId') {
                    return wizard.next();
                }

                var seasonVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:name_season_input').value;
                var dateFromVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:dateFrom_input').value;
                var dateToVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:dateTo_input').value;
                /*var compNameVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:title_input').value;*/

                var isValidName = validateFieldsInOtherTournament('manageTournament', ['title'], lang);
                if (isValidName) {
                    if (validRuContentT) {
                        var filledBothDate = (dateFromVal != "" &amp;&amp; dateToVal != "");
                        var isEmptySeason = ("" != String(seasonVal));
                        if ( filledBothDate || isEmptySeason) {
                            return wizard.next();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return "competitionId"; // currentTab
            }
```

I use code [js wizard](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/core/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/wizard/wizard.js?spec=svn2661&r=2661). But it still doesn't work.(

**//UPDATED**

```
I try to do something like this

 function validateManageOtherTournaments(wizard, validationTab, lang) {
                /*var wizardElement = document.getElementById('wiz');*/

                var currentTabId = validationTab;
                if (currentTabId != 'competitionId') {
                    var currentStepIndex = wizard.getStepIndex(wizard.getState().currentStep),
                            stepIndexToGo = currentStepIndex + 1;
                    var stepIdToGo = wizard.cfg.steps[stepIndexToGo];
                    return wizard.loadStep(stepIdToGo, stepIndexToGo, false);        // next
                }

                var seasonVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:name_season_input').value;
                var dateFromVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:dateFrom_input').value;
                var dateToVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:dateTo_input').value;
                /*var compNameVal = document.getElementById('manageTournament:title_input').value;*/

                var isValidName = validateFieldsInOtherTournament('manageTournament', ['title'], lang);
                if (isValidName) {
                    if (validRuContentT) {
                        var filledBothDate = (dateFromVal != "" &amp;&amp; dateToVal != "");
                        var isEmptySeason = ("" != String(seasonVal));
                        if ( filledBothDate || isEmptySeason) {
                            var currentStepIndex = wizard.getStepIndex(wizard.getState().currentStep),
                                    stepIndexToGo = currentStepIndex + 1;
                            var stepIdToGo = wizard.cfg.steps[stepIndexToGo];
                            return wizard.loadStep(stepIdToGo, stepIndexToGo, false);         // next
                        }
                    }
                }
                var currentStepIndex = wizard.getStepIndex(this.getState().currentStep),
                stepIndexToGo = currentStepIndex;
                var stepIdToGo = wizard.cfg.steps[stepIndexToGo];
                return wizard.loadStep(stepIdToGo, stepIndexToGo, false);     //competitionId
            }
```

How I can return in onnext function tab of wizard?

Comment: Can't really understand your question. Do you want to navigate to a specific tab from the `onnext` callback?

Comment: @kolossus Yes, I want validate fields and if result is correct navigate to next tab in other case stay on current tab

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to do this validation in your backing bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this:

```
public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event)
{
  if (!event.getOldStep().equals("competitionId"))
  {
    return event.getNewStep();
  }
  if (validationPassed())
  {
    return event.getNewStep();
  }
  else
  {
    return event.getOldStep();
  }
}

private boolean validationPassed()
{
  // do your validation here.
  // return true if validation passed
}
```

Then in my wizard: `flowListener="#{myBean.onFlowProcess}"`

Comment: This doesn't require the wizard to be bound to the bean (in your code the wizard is only used to get the current tab). Most likely you will need to be working with a @ViewScoped bean.

Comment: I did something similar @KidTempo but when validations fails and it returns event.getOldStep(), it stays on the page but the Next button disappears. Do you know what might be happening?